# Unable to see java compiler line for failed build that provides hint or redirects to error path

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This is how the build window shows java compiler error in other machine having the same android studio, same project.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuCA1.jpg

[In other machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuCA1.jpg)

This is how the same project, same error, Android studio is reacting to in my machine having the same android studio version

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjSN7.jpg

[My Machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjSN7.jpg)

https://imgur.com/a/TH6VX4T

[My Machine](https://imgur.com/a/TH6VX4T)

An error has been generated intentionally to show the actual problem. The real problem is, I am not getting that *java compiler* line to expand in my machine so that I can get an idea where the error is actually.

I have tried to invalidate cache/restart, system restart, imported settings of another android studio that is showing that *java compiler* line.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: your Support class does not have getErrortestHere() method.

Comment: It is saying that Your model does not contain any method name with `getErrorTestHere()`.

Comment: @SaurabhBhandari The error has been generated intentionally, actual problem is I am not getting that _java compiler_ line in my android studio for any error.

Comment: android does not have any such method not in there documentation. this may be in case of testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there can be some changes in settings check setting in an android-studio 
or
if you don't want to take this long process you can try exporting of your settings(for a backup) and import settings from other pc 
I am sure it will solve your problems

or check java versions on both pcs maybe because of different java versions
this problem can be possible 
different java versions shows different errors

Comment: I have tried exporting settings of other android studio that is showing that _java compiler_ line and imported in my android studio but unfortunately, it didn't solve the problem and i am still not getting that _java compiler_ line for any error!

Comment: did you check versions of jdk in both pc??

Comment: My machine has:

openjdk version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.4)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.4, mixed mode)


Machine that shows _java compiler_ error:

java version "1.8.0_77"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_77-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.77-b03, mixed mode)

Comment: @⁨Gic Bharat Abnd⁩  so that problem of java compiler has been solved after replacing java openJdk by jdk... We took time to do so because we did not want to take any risk in the middle while the project was going on... We had plan to replace hdd by ssd too... So everything took place at once... Now I can see that _java compiler_ line...